# Cómo pongo fuentes personalizadas en HTML-PDF (Node.JS)

Tags: javascript, css, nodejs, pdf, node-html-pdf

Estoy usando la librería html-pdf para generar pdfs mediante una plantilla html en Node.js, pero no puedo colocar fuentes personalizadas, tengo en mi template html, en la etiqueta style del head el siguiente codigo, pero sin embargo la fuente que sale en el pdf es una por defecto

```
@font-face {
            src: url(file:///assets/fonts/BebasNeue-Regular.otf);
            font-family: "Bebas";
        }
```

Comment: Hace tiempo tuve un problema similar (no eran las fuentes, pero sí algunos estilos que no se mostraban al momento de imprimir). La solución es hacer uso de los [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), en específico el de `print`. Ahí defines los estilos que serán específicos para imprimir la página.

Comment: Gracias por mencionarlo, pero si aplico el @media print{} y coloco la fuente dentro, sucede que los elementos que tienen la fuente simplemente desaparecen :c

Comment: ¿Solamente aplicas el `font-family`? ¿O aplicas alguna otra regla dentro del estilo? Intenta jugar con el `display`.

Comment: Si, solo modifico el font-family, lo demas son estilos como bordes de la tabla, y el color de los mismos, nada muy conflictivo, así que dudo que sea ese el problema, algo que no mencioné y que posiblemente tenga algo que ver es que estoy ejecutando el script desde una aplicación electron.js, quizá que no haya un navegador como tal puede ser el causante del problema, ¿Qué piensas al respecto...?

Comment: Pues es lo único que se me ocurre, que pruebes con los distintos valores de `display`.